# VAR data not pushing to SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a slight issue and I'm not sure why. Maybe someone can help me out. First a few disclaimers; I'm still learning PHP, I'm aware of mysqli or pdo but the server this will live on is running an old ver 4 of php.

Ok now on to the problem.

I have a form which passes to my post-data.php form to push to SQL db.

However when it pushes the data it's only pushing the variables not the data within the vars from post action of the form.

[Screenshot of submitted data in PHPmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K56oi.jpg)

My Code follows:

```
<?php
    $hostname = "localhost"; $username = "goldme_owner";
    $dbName = "goldme_dealer_meeting";

    $connect = mysql_connect($hostname, $username);
    if (!$connect) { 
        echo "Please try later."; 
    } 
    else { 
        mysql_select_db($dbName, $connect); 
        $checkboxA1 = isset($_POST['checkboxA1']) ? $_POST['checkboxA1'] : 'No';
        $checkboxE1 = isset($_POST['checkboxE1']) ? $_POST['checkboxE1'] : 'No';
        $checkboxF1 = isset($_POST['checkboxF1']) ? $_POST['checkboxF1'] : 'No';
        $checkboxG1 = isset($_POST['checkboxG1']) ? $_POST['checkboxG1'] : 'No';
        $checkboxH1 = isset($_POST['checkboxH1']) ? $_POST['checkboxH1'] : 'No';
        $checkboxI1 = isset($_POST['checkboxI1']) ? $_POST['checkboxI1'] : 'No';
        $checkboxJ1 = isset($_POST['checkboxJ1']) ? $_POST['checkboxJ1'] : 'No';
        $checkboxK1 = isset($_POST['checkboxK1']) ? $_POST['checkboxK1'] : 'No';
    }

    echo "$checkboxA1"; //just want to make sure checkbox vars are passing //will delete in final code
    echo "$checkboxE1"; //just want to make sure checkbox vars are passing //will delete in final code
    echo "$checkboxF1"; //just want to make sure checkbox vars are passing //will delete in final code
    echo "$checkboxG1"; //just want to make sure checkbox vars are passing //will delete in final code
    echo "$checkboxH1"; //just want to make sure checkbox vars are passing //will delete in final code
    echo "$checkboxI1"; //just want to make sure checkbox vars are passing //will delete in final code
    echo "$checkboxJ1"; //just want to make sure checkbox vars are passing //will delete in final code
    echo "$checkboxK1"; //just want to make sure checkbox vars are passing //will delete in final code
    echo "$_POST[confirm]"; //just want to make sure confirm code generated //will delete in final code

        $sql_statement = 'INSERT INTO 2014_registrations'. 
        '(confirm_number,timecode,company_name,country,address1,address2,city'.
        ',state,zip,phone,fax,email,zone_manager,transport,first_name,'.
        'last_name,tuesday_tours,tuesday_meat,wed_lunch,wed_dinner,'.
        'wed_pool_tourney,thurs_lunch,thurs_dinner,fri_shop,fri_tour,dietary)'.
        'VALUES ("$_POST[confirm]","$_POST[timecode]","$_POST[company_name]",'.
        '"$_POST[address]","$_POST[address2]","$_POST[city]","$_POST[state]",'.
        '"$_POST[zip]","$_POST[country]","$_POST[phone]","$_POST[fax]",'.
        '"$_POST[email]","$_POST[zonemanager]","$_POST[transport]",'.
        '"$_POST[fattendee1]","$_POST[lattendee1]","$_POST[checkboxA1]",'.
        '"$_POST[radio1]","$_POST[checkboxE1]","$_POST[checkboxF1]",'.
        '"$_POST[checkboxG1]","$_POST[checkboxH1]","$_POST[checkboxI1]",'.
        '"$_POST[checkboxJ1]","$_POST[checkboxK1]","$_POST[dietary1]")';


    $rec_insert = mysql_query($sql_statement);
    if(! $rec_insert ){
        die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "Entered data successfully\n";
    mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). And you need to learn basic PHP syntax: `'`-quoted strings do not act like `"`-quoted strings: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: PHP 5 was released 10 years ago, so you might want to consider updating to a more recent version. Also, database normalization might make your system more re-usable and you would avoid table- and column names like `2014_registrations`, `wed_dinner`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside single quotes the variables are not read as variables. For example `echo '$a'` will print `$a` but `echo "$a"` will print the value of `$a`.

In your code you are trying to use something similar to `'$a'`, or in other words you are using single quotes around variables instead of double quotes.

Try writing it as

```
"VALUES ('$_POST[confirm]','$_POST[timecode]','$_POST[company_name]',".
```

or

```
'VALUES ("'.$_POST[confirm].'","'.$_POST[timecode].'","'.$_POST[company_name].'",'.
```

and so on..

Note that the use of `$_POST[confirm]` gives an notice. The correct way to use it is `$_POST['confirm']`.

Also note that your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Consider using prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

The variables are being read as strings because they're written in single quotes.

I've moved the variables to outside of the single quotes and just concatenated them to the string. **This code is extremely susceptible to SQL injection and should not be used in a production environment.**

```
$sql_statement = 'INSERT INTO 2014_registrations'. 
'(confirm_number,timecode,company_name,country,address1,address2,city'.
',state,zip,phone,fax,email,zone_manager,transport,first_name,'.
'last_name,tuesday_tours,tuesday_meat,wed_lunch,wed_dinner,'.
'wed_pool_tourney,thurs_lunch,thurs_dinner,fri_shop,fri_tour,dietary)'.
'VALUES ("'.$_POST[confirm].'","'.$_POST[timecode].'","'.$_POST[company_name].'",'.
'"'.$_POST[address].'","'.$_POST[address2].'","'.$_POST[city].'","'.$_POST[state].'",'.
'"'.$_POST[zip].'","'.$_POST[country].'","'.$_POST[phone].'","'.$_POST[fax].'",'.
'"'.$_POST[email].'","'.$_POST[zonemanager].'","'.$_POST[transport].'",'.
'"'.$_POST[fattendee1].'","'.$_POST[lattendee1].'","'.$_POST[checkboxA1].'",'.
'"'.$_POST[radio1].'","'.$_POST[checkboxE1].'","'.$_POST[checkboxF1].'",'.
'"'.$_POST[checkboxG1].'","'.$_POST[checkboxH1].'","'.$_POST[checkboxI1].'",'.
'"'.$_POST[checkboxJ1].'","'.$_POST[checkboxK1].'","'.$_POST[dietary1].'")';
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, inserting data directly into the db from POST request is almost never a good idea.

I know this is really badly formatted, but try using this $sql_statement instead:

```
$sql_statement = 'INSERT INTO 2014_registrations'. 
    '(confirm_number,timecode,company_name,country,address1,address2,city'.
    ',state,zip,phone,fax,email,zone_manager,transport,first_name,'.
    'last_name,tuesday_tours,tuesday_meat,wed_lunch,wed_dinner,'.
    'wed_pool_tourney,thurs_lunch,thurs_dinner,fri_shop,fri_tour,dietary)'.
    "VALUES (\"{$_POST[confirm]}\",\"{$_POST[timecode]}\",\"{$_POST[company_name]}\",".
    "\"{$_POST[address]}\",\"{$_POST[address2]}\",\"{$_POST[city]}\",\"{$_POST[state]}\",".
    "\"{$_POST[zip]}\",\"{$_POST[country]}\",\"{$_POST[phone]}\",\"{$_POST[fax]}\",".
    "\"{$_POST[email]}\",\"{$_POST[zonemanager]}\",\"{$_POST[transport]}\",".
    "\"{$_POST[fattendee1]}\",\"{$_POST[lattendee1]}\",\"{$_POST[checkboxA1]}\",".
    "\"{$_POST[radio1]}\",\"{$_POST[checkboxE1]}\",\"{$_POST[checkboxF1]}\",".
    "\"{$_POST[checkboxG1]}\",\"{$_POST[checkboxH1]}\",\"{$_POST[checkboxI1]}\",".
    "\"{$_POST[checkboxJ1]}\",\"{$_POST[checkboxK1]}\",\"{$_POST[dietary1]}\")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `sql_statment is wrong.

```
$sql_statement = 'INSERT INTO 2014_registrations'. 
    '(confirm_number,timecode,company_name,country,address1,address2,city'.
    ',state,zip,phone,fax,email,zone_manager,transport,first_name,'.
    'last_name,tuesday_tours,tuesday_meat,wed_lunch,wed_dinner,'.
    'wed_pool_tourney,thurs_lunch,thurs_dinner,fri_shop,fri_tour,dietary)'.
    'VALUES ("$_POST[confirm]","$_POST[timecode]","$_POST[company_name]",'.
    '"$_POST[address]","$_POST[address2]","$_POST[city]","$_POST[state]",'.
    '"$_POST[zip]","$_POST[country]","$_POST[phone]","$_POST[fax]",'.
    '"$_POST[email]","$_POST[zonemanager]","$_POST[transport]",'.
    '"$_POST[fattendee1]","$_POST[lattendee1]","$_POST[checkboxA1]",'.
    '"$_POST[radio1]","$_POST[checkboxE1]","$_POST[checkboxF1]",'.
    '"$_POST[checkboxG1]","$_POST[checkboxH1]","$_POST[checkboxI1]",'.
    '"$_POST[checkboxJ1]","$_POST[checkboxK1]","$_POST[dietary1]")';
```

Change to:

```
$sql_statment = "INSERT INTO 2014_registrations". 
    "(confirm_number,timecode,company_name,country,address1,address2,city".
    ",state,zip,phone,fax,email,zone_manager,transport,first_name,".
    "last_name,tuesday_tours,tuesday_meat,wed_lunch,wed_dinner,".
    "wed_pool_tourney,thurs_lunch,thurs_dinner,fri_shop,fri_tour,dietary)".
    "VALUES ($_POST['confirm'],$_POST['timecode'],$_POST['company_name'],".
    "$_POST['address'],$_POST['address2'],$_POST['city'],$_POST['state'],".
    "$_POST['zip'],$_POST['country],$_POST[phone'],$_POST['fax'],".
    "$_POST['email'],$_POST['zonemanager'],$_POST['transport'],".
    "$_POST['fattendee1'],$_POST['lattendee1'],$_POST['checkboxA1'],".
    "$_POST['radio1'],$_POST['checkboxE1'],$_POST['checkboxF1'],".
    "$_POST['checkboxG1'],$_POST['checkboxH1'],$_POST['checkboxI1'],".
    "$_POST['checkboxJ1'],$_POST['checkboxK1'],$_POST['dietary1']")";
```

If you are using `$sql_statment = ''` you cant put a variable in `$sql_statment = '$_POST[confirm]';` because it will treat it like a text. You have to make it like `$sql_statment = $_POST['checkboxG1'].','.$_POST['checkboxH1'].','.$_POST['checkboxI1'].','.`
Another way is to change it all to `$sql_statment = "$_POST['checkboxG1'],$_POST['checkboxH1'],$_POST['checkboxI1'],";` like I did.

See that there is a differance in using '  and ";

Btw. you should use some security for example `mysql_escape_string`.